# Efficient algorithms for detecting finite topologies

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, computational-mathematics

Given a finite collection $X$ of finite sets, what are some efficient methods for deciding whether or not $X$ is a topology?

Obviously it is possible to brute-force the problem by checking the conditions $\emptyset\in X$, and $\bigcup Y\in X$, $\bigcap Y\in X$ for every $Y\in \mathcal{P}(X)$; but this is extremely inefficient - $O\left(2^{|X|}\right)$, I think - for large $X$. Is there a faster way to check if $X$ is a topology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way: for each $x \in X$ compute $M_x= \bigcap\{O \in \mathcal{T}: x \in O\}$ a finite intersection of open sets, hence open. So check also that the computed $M_x \in \mathcal{T}$ as well. If you have some incidence data structure (so for each $x \in X, O \in \mathcal{T}$ a boolean to determine $x \in O$ or not), this is a simple loop to compute. Then for each (non-empty) open set $O$, check whether the $M_x$ inside it union up to $O$: for any $x \in O$ check whether $M_x \subseteq O$: if not, "no topology", else remove $M_x$ from $O$ till $O$ is empty, and try the next $O$. Precise implementation will depend on your data structures, and this is not a programming site. This will run in about $|\mathcal{T}| \cdot |X|$ steps, I think.

Comment: I was more worried about the general principle than the specific implementation, so this is fine.

Comment: @R.Burton $x \le y$ iff $y \in M_x$ defines a pre-order on $X$ if we have a topology. Maybe algorithms to check for those are available in libraries?

Comment: @R.Burton I now check that all sets in $\mathcal{T}$ are indeed open and belong in it, but I don't see an easy way (non-bruteforce) to check we have *all* of the open sets..

Comment: Since this is for finite spaces, you can use the same algorithm on the closed sets - i.e. take $M_x'=\bigcap\{O\in\mathcal{T}:x\notin O\}$.