# Algorithm to enumerate all topologies of order $n$.

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, computational-mathematics

I need to generate all finite topologies of orders up to $6$ (may be even $7$). The brute force approach applying the $3$ axioms of topology for all element combinations requires numerous iterations ($2^{2^n}$ for order $n$).  The program I built works fine for orders up to $5$. Orders $6$ and beyond, it doesn't finish running (as it takes $2^{64}$ iterations for order $6$). I am curious to know if anyone has a better algorithm to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whenever you have two open sets, their union is also open. In each step, you only have to iterate for subsets that cannot be determined at this point. See also [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A000798).

Comment: Pick a minimal neighbourhood $M_x$ (as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3551342/4280)) for each point of the set and make sure it obeys $y \in M_x \to M_y \subseteq M_x$ as well.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, thanks for your quick response. Just to make sure I understand, let us take an example for order 3 with X = {1,2,3}. Let us start with the discrete topology (so that we cover all open sets): $\tau$ = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}} (excluded empty set $\emptyset$ as it has no relevance). Intersection or union of any two open sets automatically $\in \tau$. I am not able to see how this simplifies the processing. Can you please elaborate?